# How to capture broken image urls with javascript then pass the urls to php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a site that displays a lot of external images and thumbnails etc, easily up to 100 on a single page. I crawl and index the urls to the images and save them in mysql and display them with this code inside simple loops from queries.

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['img_url']; ?>" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://example.com/image.jpg';" width="150" height="150">
```

I use that particular code to replace any broken image urls with a default image.

My question is, is it possible to use javascripts onerror or something else to capture the image url that is broken when a broken url is found so that I can pass the url back to php and be able to automatically delete the urls from my database?
I am not very good with javascript and after searching I can't seem to find anything similar to what I am looking for, I mostly just find lots of posts on how to replace the broken image.
I am open to any ideas really, the original image urls come from `$row['img_url']` as you can see in the code but I know I need javascript or something to catch the errors and then somehow get the urls passed back to php so that I can automate the deletion process instead of just replacing images with default images like my currnt code.

Comment: Okay, images are external - but why don't you set up a crawler that verifies those images? Add a column (or an extra table) holding the last time you verified a given `img_url`, then periodically check that the image is there. **Usual caveats about hotlinking apply.**

Comment: Yeah I could do that I just thought maybe there would be an easy way to just capture the errors with onerror or something and send the urls back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Simply replace this:

```
this.src='http://example.com/image.jpg'
```

with:

```
this.src='http://example.com/image-missing.php?url={$row['primaryKey']}&w=150&h=150'
```

Now, "image-missing.php" receives the URL of the missing file and the intended size of the missing image. What it needs to do is clean the database (**after checking that the call is legitimate (1) and that the referred row exists(2)**), *and output a replacement image* in the proper size.

---

(1) otherwise you have just handed the possibility of **deleting your whole image database** to the first guy with time on his hands.

(2) someone else might have loaded the same page, and called the same script one millisecond ago.

Comment: This seems like a decent way to do it, I am already able to get the urls now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `file_exists` to check like so:

```
if(file_exists($row['img_url'])){
   echo '<img src="'.$row['img_url'].'" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src="http://example.com/image.jpg";" width="150" height="150">';
}
```

Comment: I don't thnk that will work because I think file_exists only works for local paths and not remote urls.

Comment: not true @rich see the manual page: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: This *might* work but, on the other hand, it might not. Say that file_exists is not allowed to open external URLs, or that the external image, if missing, does a 302 redirect to a HTML page (which is commoner than you would think). You need at the very least to *download* the image and verify it is an image, not just a simple `file_exists`. (On the other hand, this *is* a useful check before trying the actual download: if it fails, then the image for sure is not there).

Comment: Yeah, it would probably be easier just to crawl all the urls in the database periodically. I was just wondering if there is an easy way with javascript cause it works good to replace broken links to images.

Comment: bit extreme to download on every call, would not be practical in most cases, would be better taking copies in the first place and serving them.

Comment: well i gave you an 'easy' way with php, use it, or not :-) cant be much easier to be honest.

Comment: This approach actually has the advantage of being able to purge at least **some** images before even sending the output to the user. It risks slowing down the page like crazy, but I still have to +1 the simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this (example uses vanilla JS, no jquery or any 3rd party library):

```
var allImages = document.querySelectorAll('img');
for (var i = 0; i < deleteLink.length; i++) {
    document.querySelector('img').addEventListener('error', function(e) {
        // Delete a user
        var url = "<DELETION_URL>";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("DELETE", url+'?resource=' + e.target.src, true);
    });
}
```

`<DELETION-URL>` should point to a PHP script that accepts `DELETE` (or at least `POST`) requests and read the resource parameter. It will then remove the image provided that resource is truly missing.

Comment: "*...after checking that the request is legitimate and justified*" if you please :-) -- we don't need an introduction to Little Bobby Images.